# /dev/urandom in perl code

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I am trying to generate random number for some specific use within my perl code.

I am able to figure out command for linux and its working fine.

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=' | fold -w 10 | grep -i '[!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=]' | head -n 1
```

I am not able to make the same command work in perl. I am very new to perl and programming.

I tried researching about same but not able to make it work in perl.

Any suggestions or any other ways if someone can suggest how i can generate random numbers in perl.

Let me know if any questions.
Thanks for help

Comment: is your perl script running on linux too?  or something else?

Comment: yes running on linux

Comment: hum, that doesn't generate a *number*.

Comment: What have you tried in Perl? Please show us your code that doesn't work. Also, please explain what you're trying to do. The best way to do it in Perl is almost certainly not by stringing together a series of Unix commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following, although it's not up to cryptographical standards:

```
my @syms = ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9', split(//, '-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=') );

my $random = join '', map $syms[rand(@syms)], 1..10;
```

The following is an improvement to your original solution, if you're trying to generate a password. While it decreases the entropy of the password (making it more vulnerable to brute force attacks that noone uses), it increases its chances of resisting a dictionary attack by guaranteeing a mix of character types.

```
my @lc = 'a'..'z';
my @uc = 'A'..'Z';
my @na = ( '0'..'9', split(//, '-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=') );

@$_ = grep !/^[0O1liI]\z/, @$_
    for \@lc, \@uc, \@na;

my @all = ( @lc, @uc, @na );

sub gen_password {
    return
        join '',
            shuffle
                map($all[rand(@all)], 1..4),
                map($lc[rand(@lc)],   1..2),
                map($uc[rand(@uc)],   1..2),
                map($na[rand(@na)],   1..2);
}
```